# Filter object keys, inbetween dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to test for a date in between a date range using `Moment`

```
const startDate = new Date(dates[0].year, dates[0].day, dates[0].month),
  endDate = new Date(
    dates[lastItemIndex - 1].year,
    dates[lastItemIndex - 1].day,
    dates[lastItemIndex - 1].month
  );
newEvents = Object.keys(events).filter(key => {
  moment()
    .range(startDate, endDate)
    .contains(moment(key).toDate());
});
```

My `events` object is:

```
{
  2018-09-11: {
    dots: Array(4),
    disabled: false,
    selected: true,
    selectedColor: "#00CCCB",
    customStyles: {…}
  }
  2018-09-12: {
    dots: Array(2),
    disabled: false,
    selected: true,
    selectedColor: "#00CCCB",
    customStyles: {…}
  }
  2018-09-13: {
    dots: Array(2),
    disabled: false,
    selected: true,
    selectedColor: "#00CCCB",
    customStyles: {…}
  }
  2018-09-14: {
    dots: Array(1),
    disabled: false,
    selected: true,
    selectedColor: "#00CCCB",
    customStyles: {…}
  }
}
```

How can I filter my object keys using a date range?

Comment: There may be a better solution than this - you can traverse Object.keys() and convert each date into timestamp first then check if that timestamp is between your range or not

Comment: it might help, if your filter function would return something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, except, it doesn't set the filtered events anywhere. You can either modify your code to set newEvents like `newEvents[key] = events[key]`, or you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this.

```
const dateRange = moment().range(startDate, endDate),
newEvents = Object.keys(events).reduce((output, dateString) => {
    dateRange.contains(moment(dateString).toDate()) && (output[dateString] = events[dateString])
    return output
}, {})
```

Please note, I have moved `dateRange` outside the loop for efficiency, but it is actually not required. Also, I have not changed the *date range* logic. But momentjs is not required here, like @Abhay said in the comments, you can simply use timestamps.

Comment: How can I reduce the array to create a new array with the dates and data? I only get an array of dates - I need the object with each key too, dots, disabled, selected etc

Comment: @Bomber were you able to try the code in my answer within your context? This should exactly do what you're asking, return an array of objects with date and related data. Could you share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code if this still isn't working.

Comment: I was not able to run the code since you didn't add moment.js and required plugins to the fiddle. But it definitely seems like an oversight on my part, there was a missing parentheses in my code. See my updated answer, i have changed `output[dateString] = events[dateString]` to `(output[dateString] = events[dateString])`.

Comment: how would I be able to add another property for each key?